# trouble in inserting record to database using PHP mysqli oops

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, oop

I am using PHP mysqli to access and insert record to database and also prepared statements but somewhere there is an error i couldn't figure out.. pointing out the mistake will be very much helpful

mailer.php

```
<?php 

class Submit {

    const DB = 'localhost',
          USER = 'test',
          PASS = '123456',
          DB_NAME = 'testing';


  private $mysql;


  public function __construct() {

      $this->mysql = new mysqli(self::DB , self::USER , self::PASS , self::DB_NAME);

      if ($this->mysql->connect_errno) {
          echo "Error: " . $this->mysql->connect_error;
          echo "<br>";
          echo "Error code: " . $this->mysql->connect_errno;
      }


    }

    public function addRecord($record) {

        $status = false;

        $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (name,message) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = $this->mysql->prepare($query);

        if ( $stmt ) {

            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $record->name , $record->message);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $status = ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) ? true : false;

                $stmt->fetch_object();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }

        return $status;
    }

}


$submit = new Submit();

$result = null;

if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : '';
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? trim($_POST['message']) : '';

    $result = $submit->addRecord($name,$message);

    if ($result) {
        echo "Message Saved";


    }
}
```

Also i am using ajax call from an external file containing a form and scripts within that

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Contact Form | PHP, AJAX and MySQL</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <form id="submit_form">  
                    <label for="name">Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label for="message">Message</label>  
                     <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                     <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>  
                     <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>  
                </form>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script> 

 jQuery(function($){  

        $('form#submit_form').submit(function(e){  
          e.preventDefault();
           var name = $(this).find('#name').val(),
               message = $(this).find('#message').val();  

           if(name == '' || message == '') {  
                $('#error_message').html("All Fields are required");  
           }  

           else {  
                $('#error_message').html('');  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"mailer.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{
                         name: name, 
                         message: message
                     },  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $("form").trigger("reset");  
                          $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data).fadeOut(3000);  

                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });  

 </script>
```

Comment: "*..but somewhere there is an error..*" Ok. What Error? Please Paste Your Error In Question.

Comment: No specific error..I actually meant error in code.....the record isnt getting inserted into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving 2 parameters to your addRecord() method, but it expects only 1. But, it seems it expects an object which you are not initializing so I adjusted it, so it takes the two parameters you are giving it.

```
public function addRecord($name, $message) {

    $status = false;

    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (name,message) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = $this->mysql->prepare($query);

    if ( $stmt ) {

        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name , $message);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $status = $stmt->affected_rows === 1;
        }
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Also I removed some unnecessary steps in the method:

```
$status = ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) ? true : false;
$status = $stmt->affected_rows === 1;
```

The comparison itself will return a boolean, so no need to use an explicit structure.

```
$stmt->fetch_object();
$stmt->close();
```

Fetching the object without ever using it is a waste.
When leaving the scope of the method, the garbage collector will unset the stmt.

**Code to test the function:**

```
class Submit {

const DB = 'localhost',
      USER = 'test',
      PASS = '123456',
      DB_NAME = 'testing';
  private $mysql;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->mysql = new mysqli(self::DB , self::USER , self::PASS , self::DB_NAME);
      if ($this->mysql->connect_errno) {
          echo "Error: " . $this->mysql->connect_error;
          echo "<br>";
          echo "Error code: " . $this->mysql->connect_errno;
      }
    }

    public function addRecord($name, $message) {
        $status = false;
        $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (name,message) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = $this->mysql->prepare($query);
        if ( $stmt ) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name , $message);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $status = $stmt->affected_rows === 1;
            }
        }
        return $status;
    }
}


$submit = new Submit();

$result = null;
$name = "dsfdsf";
$message = "message";
$result = $submit->addRecord($name,$message);
var_dump($result); // bool(true)
```

Comment: I fixed it, but the record still hasn't inserted

Comment: The new code is correct. Have you checked whether you are receiving your `$_POST` values?

Comment: I modified the code a little, You said the addRecord method expects an object so i casted them..please have a look at the code https://codeshare.io/CWu7L

Comment: looks fine, I copy pasted it and it worked with my dummy data. Add `var_dump($_POST);exit;` before calling `addRecord()` to make sure you are having the correct data

Comment: I guess there is something wrong the script more specifically the ajax call, not even the vat_dump showing anything...should I json_decode what being sent from the PHP file in the ajax call??

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the javascript from your ajax call?

Comment: done....please check

Comment: Got it. In your ajax you are only sending name and message, but in your backend you are first checking for `$_POST['submit']` which you are not sending.

Comment: So what do I change in my backend code? Could you please elaborate I am a beginner ...

Comment: Instead of `if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {` You could use `if (isset($_POST['name']) ) {`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, So glad it worked.....thanks once again